# akka and streaming output

Tags: java, akka

I'm using Akka with servlet container. The servlet creates an HTTP actor for each request, which hold the reference to async response object

```
public void search(@FormParam("search") String param, @Suspended final AsyncResponse response);
```

The HTTP actor creates an 'worker' actor which then queries the database using an async driver. Now, the async driver returns an iterator and I wonder if it does fit into idea of actors passing messages to each other. Because the iterator is not really a ready response message, but rather a reference. It will probably not work if the actors would be on different hosts. So my question is, what is the right way to handle streaming output in Akka?

Comment: Couldn't the iterator be viewed as a shared mailbox that the driver puts messages into, and the consumer takes messages out on, with the additional constraint that the consumer can't retrieve messages in an order different from the order of insertion?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure it will work for your use case but the current trend for stream processing is functional reactive programming of which Akka has [Akka Streams](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-stream-scala).

The basic idea is where ever you have an iterator in a reactive system you should be instead using a reactive like stream. That being said Akka support for that seems early so your mileage may vary.